# C# How to invoke clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibrary) using Reflection?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dll, reflection

I am new to C# and I would like to know how to invoke the below code via Reflection.

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteURL);
List documentList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibrary);
```

It has the dependency on `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`.

I was able to create the clientContext Object. However, I am not able to invoke the other part i.e.,

`Web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibrary);`

Below is my code to create the clientContext.

```
        Type clinetContext = null;
        foreach (Type type in sharePointClientTypes)
            if (type.FullName.Equals("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext"))
            {
                clinetContext = type;
                break;
            }

        ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = clinetContext.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string) });
        object context = constructorInfo.Invoke(new string[] { siteURL });
```

Can anyone help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Try use this

```
Web web = clinetContext.Web;
clinetContext.Load(web);
web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
List documentsList = web.Lists.GetByTitle(documentLibrary);
clinetContext.Load(documentsList);
web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```